# "The average teenager’s brain differs from that of an adult. "

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, phrase-meaning

I was wondering if the following sentence is correct:

> The average teenager’s brain differs from that of an adult.

Can the place holder "from that of" be used in the sentence above?

Comment: Why do you doubt it?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes.

In my opinion, I consider the usage slightly formal, so I would say ***"from an adult's",*** where *"adult's"* is a possessive pronoun. It works the same, and means the same.